# Is there a way to load videos using Three.js LoadingManager?

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-video

I'm using THREE.LoadingManager with multiple loaders, to manage the loading of textures, models, images and cubeTextures before displaying my app.
This allows me to display a loading bar showing the global loading progress, and it works just fine:

```js
const loadingManager = new LoadingManager();
// ...
smaaImageLoader = new SMAAImageLoader(loadingManager);
textureLoader = new TextureLoader(loadingManager);
gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);
cubeTextureLoader = new CubeTextureLoader(loadingManager);
```

But I'm struggling to load videos this way.
I wish there was a video loader that I could use this way:

```js
videoLoader = new VideoLoader(loadingManager); // Can't do that
```

If the only way to load videos is to do it "manually" in javascript, is there any way I could communicate to the loadingManager that videos are pending, then loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to load videos using Three.js LoadingManager?

No, this is not possible. However, you can do this:

```js
const video = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'video' );
video.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', onVideoLoad, false );

video.src = url;
video.preload = "auto";

video.setAttribute( 'webkit-playsinline', 'webkit-playsinline' );
video.setAttribute( 'playsinline', '' );

manager.itemStart( url ); // notifying about start of loading process

function onVideoLoad() {

    video.removeEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', onVideoLoad, false );
    manager.itemEnd( url ); // notifying about end of loading process

}
```

Implementing a loader is problematic for multiple reasons:

- Compared to images, certain formats like OGG are not supported by all browsers. Defining multiple sources via HTML is more flexible than using fixed URLs with a potential `VideoLoader`. That would require a capabilities check before you load the video from the backend.
- Attributes and config settings of video elements might vary from use case to use case e.g. (muted, looped etc.). Images are more simple in this context. Hence, it's problematic to do this inside a video loader.
- Projects might prefer events like `canplay` or `canplaythrough` over `loadedmetadata`. Downloading the complete video is not recommended in most cases.

Comment: if you have questions about the `manager`, just like I did; this page is super useful -> https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager also I found this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59601156/load-video-using-three-js interesting if you want to create a `VideoTexture`. I myself got a mixed solution using this 3 resourses